# Suggested edits not updating

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

Because a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

The icon indicating how many suggested edits is not updating. I have refreshed the page multiple times, and even opened a new one, but it's always showing "2", no matter what I do.

Just thought I should report that.

Comment: I raised this same thing at some point - if you've been suggesting edits to tags, that '2' represents *your* edits, which the review queue won't let you review. yes it's a UI bug but apparently to check the reviews against your ID/that number would be an expensive process

Comment: Here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8339/28182